# Is it possible to `marshal` data into a Realm object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, realm

I have the following JSON coming from an API:

```
{
    "id": "7",
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "last_name": "Bar"
}
```

And I would like my Realm object to look like this (objective-c):

```
@interface RWUser : RLMObject

@property int key;
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;

@end
```

The point being that the property names are subtly different to better fit the target environment, Objective-C. `id` is reserved in Objective-C so that one really needs to change, the other two are just cosmetic but I'm assuming that a solution to `id` can also be applied to the other two.

Let's assume that I can't change what the API is outputting.

I have tried overriding `- (instancetype) initWithObject:(id)object;` but mine doesn't get called, execution jumps straight to the `RLMObject` version.

I thought about writing a marshalling method to call before I pass my data to `initWithObject`. However, that doesn't work when nesting Realm object inside one another without getting a bit more involved. I'll do that if there's no general solution.

Comment: Have you taken a look at RealmJSON?

Comment: I have now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import out of the box when your models have different properties than the JSON keys. We are still working on supporting this. Your best bet will be to use something like [RealmJSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON), [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle), or any other mapping library to import the correct keys